# Set a Map attribute from one collection object to the other collection object in java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a following class where my goal is to create the following JSON output for class BeanA

```
[
   {
      "name": "name1",
      "beanMap": {
         "custom_colum": "custom_value1"
      }
   },
   {
      "name": "name2",
      "beanMap": {
         "custom_colum": "custom_value2"
      }
   }
]
```

I am not able to figure out after creating the map from EntityA how to set the each Map values to BeanA class. The idea is that I want to first iterate over the EntityA List to create the map and then set the each map to BeanA object which is another collection.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class CopyMapAttributeToPojo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<EntityA> entityAs = new ArrayList<>();
        EntityA entityA1 = new EntityA();
        entityA1.setName("name1");
        entityA1.setCustom_column("custom_value1");

        EntityA entityA2 = new EntityA();
        entityA2.setName("name2");
        entityA2.setCustom_column("custom_value2");

        entityAs.add(entityA1);
        entityAs.add(entityA2);

        List<BeanA> beanAs = new ArrayList<>();
        BeanA beanA1 = new BeanA();
        beanA1.setName("name1");

        BeanA beanA2 = new BeanA();
        beanA2.setName("name2");

        beanAs.add(beanA1);
        beanAs.add(beanA2);

        for (EntityA a : entityAs) {
            Map<String, Object> beanObject = new HashMap<>();
            beanObject.put("custom_column", a.getCustom_column());
        }

    }

}

class EntityA {
    private String name;
    private String custom_column;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the custom_column
     */
    public String getCustom_column() {
        return custom_column;
    }

    /**
     * @param custom_column the custom_column to set
     */
    public void setCustom_column(String custom_column) {
        this.custom_column = custom_column;
    }

}

class BeanA {
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> beanMap;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the beanMap
     */
    public Map<String, Object> getBeanMap() {
        return beanMap;
    }

    /**
     * @param beanMap the beanMap to set
     */
    public void setBeanMap(Map<String, Object> beanMap) {
        this.beanMap = beanMap;
    }

}
```

Comment: so what you effectively need is a mapping from `EntityA` to `BeanA`, and the puzzling part is the creation of the map in `BeanA`?

Comment: yes, I first create the map from EntityA and then I have to set the map to BeanA. Creating the map is easy where I can iterate over EntityA object and do it but then each map needs to be set to BeanA object which is another List

Answer (score 0):

I assume you associate EntityA and BeanA by the field "name". When you iterate   EntityA List, you could record "name" and "beanMap" by another map. Then enrich BeanA in another loop. Sample code something like below. Hope it helps.

```
        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (EntityA a : entityAs) {
            Map<String, Object> beanObject = new HashMap<>();
            beanObject.put("custom_column", a.getCustom_column());
            map.put(a.getName(), beanObject);
        }

        for(BeanA beanA : beanAs) {
            beanA.setBeanMap(map.get(beanA.getName()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use specialized libraries for the mapping like [ModelMapper](https://modelmapper.org/) or [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/), but in your case a direct implementation seems to be quit simple:

You have to create the `BeanA` instances in the map where you process the `EntityA` instances and not do extra before that loop:

```java
List<BeanA> beanAs = new ArrayList<>();

for (EntityA a : entityAs) {
    BeanA beanA = new BeanA();
    beanA.setName(a.getName());

    Map<String, Object> beanMap = new HashMap<>();
    beanMap.put("custom_column", a.getCustom_column());

    beanA.setBeanMap(beanMap);

    beanAs.add(beanA);
}
```

When you only ever have a map with a single entry, you could optimize the map creation to

```java
Map<String, Object> beanMap = 
        java.util.Collections.singletonMap("custom_column", a.getCustom_column());
// no beanMap.put... necessary
```

or if you use Java 9 or newer even shorter with

```java
Map<String, Object> beanMap = Map.of("custom_column", a.getCustom_column());
// no beanMap.put... necessary
```